# Getting item from Array of HTML Objects

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a script that will get the grandparent div class of the image that is clicked.

```
<div class="first-one">
<div class="second-one></div>
<div class="third-one">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
</div>
</div>



var parentdiv = $(this).parents();
var parentarr = Object.keys(parentdiv).map(function (key) { return parentdiv[key]; });
```

This code returns an array but I am having trouble selecting the second item.

```
var getdiv = $(""+parentarr+"").eq(2); //Does not work
```

Comment: `parentarr` is just a regular `Array`, you don't need to feed it back to jQuery, just use a regular index: `var getdiv = parentarr[2];`.

Comment: Thanks Cory! I really appreciate the help!